# convert recursive mac os 9 line endings

Tags: macos, unix, line-endings

I have been having very strange issues with line endings.

I have just noticed that in Sublime Text the view/line endings shows them up as Mac OS9.

How can I convert the whole directory recursively to unix style line endings?

I want unix endings as most of my local git repos are in unix style and I have no issues with those.

I am on a windows machine but I have cygwin - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Mac OS 9 uses CR (ASCII hex code 0d) as line endings, and Mac OS X uses unix standard LF (ASCII hex code 0a)
The easy way to do is via perl.

```
perl -pi -e 's/\r/\n/g' filename
```